Why there is a difference between PDO::lastInsertId and Mysql's LAST_INSERT_ID() behavior?
My current development environment is PHP 7.2.
This is MariaDB 10.3.11.
When using PDO's lastInsertId function, if you run another query after the insert query, the lastInsertId result value will always be 0.
example table is
create table test
(
    id    int unsigned auto_increment comment 'PK' primary key,
    title varchar(128) charset utf8mb4 not null comment 'title'
)
comment 'test';

create table test2
(
    id    int unsigned auto_increment comment 'PK' primary key,
    title varchar(128) charset utf8mb4 not null comment 'title'
)
comment 'test2';

An example code is
public function pdoTest()
{
    $title = "test";
    $id = 1;

    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=<your-host>;port=<your-port>;dbname=<your-dbname>;charset=utf8', '<your-username>', '<your-password>');

    $db->beginTransaction();

    $query = "INSERT INTO test (title) VALUES (:title)";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(':title', $title);
    $stmt->execute();

    $updateQuery = "UPDATE test2 SET title = :title WHERE id = :id";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($updateQuery);
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $stmt->bindParam(':title', $title);
    $stmt->execute();

    echo $db->lastInsertId();
    $db->commit();
}


In the above situation, the return value of lastInsertId was 0. I searched the PHP site. Does anyone know why lastInsertId is not working properly?
I am wondering if only the insert query must be performed before executing the lastInsertId function.

@Olivier I was able to obtain a normal lastInsertId value. Since autoincreament is used, the ID value of the next primary key is returned.

"Since autoincrement is used" I see no auto-increment in your code. You're providing an explicit id.

@Olivier sorry. The code example seems to be wrong.
The code part has been modified. Sorry for confusing you.

Would you mind adding the code that runs  CREATE TABLE statements as well, so we won't have to do it  ourselves trying to run your code in order to understand what you mean? Strictly speaking, you are supposed to do that anyway.

I am inclined to close this question, as it's asked inappropriately. The code is full of errors and it is not clear what is asked here. The last question doesn't even make sense to me (probably a translation error but still).

@YourCommonSense Thank you for letting us know.
The example code is not actual code you would use.
This situation was created for testing purposes. CREATE TABLE will be written additionally. thank you
I will organize the questions and post them again.

I guess last id will just be reset to 0 when executing stmt::execute.

You say "the return value was 0" but your code doesn't appear to "return" anything. For all we know you could be seeing the result of the commit or something else entirely. Please read the help section on How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

@Tony
Sorry for making you so confused.
I think I wasn't able to explain properly due to my poor English.
Edited content and example code. Can you please confirm?

@YourCommonSense Sorry again.
I've edited the question and example code.
It may be inconvenient, but could you please check again? thank you

This is exactly how lastInsertId works. The manual page says, "Returns the ID of the last inserted row". SO this is why you need insert query. No insert query, no insert id. Therefore, JUST call it after insert query.

@YourCommonSense This behaviour is inconsistent with LAST_INSERT_ID() in MySQL, where even if you execute an UPDATE or SELECT query, the value will remain unchanged (https://onecompiler.com/mysql/42y46sm5x), but in PHP it becomes 0. I guess this is where the problem lies.

The PHP manual says "returns a string representing the row ID of the last row that was inserted into the database", which is misleading.

The issue was reported here and is considered expected behavior.

@shingo if Stack Overflow ever taught me anything, it's "never guess". But yes, I suppose the man page should be updated similar to https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php to make it more clear

You were already given a link that leads to the explanation. The reason for the differences between LAST_INSERT_ID() and mysql_insert_id() is that LAST_INSERT_ID() is made easy to use in scripts while mysql_insert_id() tries to provide more exact information about what happens to the AUTO_INCREMENT column.

So it's LAST_INSERT_ID() (which, for some reason, you never mention in your question) is not working properly, being too lax. While lastInsertId gives exact information.

@YourCommonSense: Please consider making your comment an answer.

When working with MySQL, PHP is using Mysql C API.
In order to retrieve the auto-increment value, PHP is calling mysql_insert_id() function from this API. And, according to MySQL documentation,

The reason for the differences between LAST_INSERT_ID() and mysql_insert_id() is that LAST_INSERT_ID() is made easy to use in scripts while mysql_insert_id() tries to provide more exact information about what happens to the AUTO_INCREMENT column.

So, it seems that things are the other way round: it's LAST_INSERT_ID()'s behavior is closer to "incorrect", as it's still returning a value after executing queries that didn't change it.
While PDO::lastInsertId() gives you more exact result, returning a value only if the last query affected the AUTO_INCREMENT column.

Your code seems mostly correct, but the issue lies in how PHP PDO works with lastInsertId(). This method only returns the ID of the last inserted record and not after an UPDATE query. Since your logic includes an UPDATE query right after the INSERT, calling $db->lastInsertId() at that point will not reflect the inserted ID anymore.
To fix this, simply move the call to $db->lastInsertId() directly after the INSERT query, and it should work as expected.

Thank you for your reply.
?
It has been confirmed that lastInsertId operates properly only after the insert query.
What I was curious about was why lastInsertId did not function normally after other queries such as UPDATE and SELECT were executed.
Do you know the clear reason?
